# Can I Inner Join 2 tables based on multiple values for a column

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is what I want,

```
TableA Inner Join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA OR TableB.ColumnA = NULL
```

I tried it and it returns empty ds?

**Edit**

Why I cannot use Right Outer Join and Left Outer Join is because I only either want common ColumnA records from Table B or ones with value NULL in ColumnA

[image]

Comment: Yes. Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Have a look on Google for LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: @MarkSinkinson Yes, I did tried it which is why asking, sorry should had added to question

Comment: @JamesAnderson I have been trying all ones from here, http://lh5.ggpht.com/-fnOQYPFr8D0/UagAzBIgMvI/AAAAAAAABbo/3fBL5Fm3Y9Y/SQL%252520JOINs.jpg

Comment: @JamesAnderson left outer join is not still not returning NULL columns

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your logic, suggesting your actual query is incorrect, or your filtering out valid records returned by this JOIN elsewhere in the query.

Comment: Post the entire query and some examples on a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: SQLFiddle would be good

Comment: OK, I am going to try now, but I have 6 tables, will take some time

Comment: I find the answer, thanks for your comments :)

Comment: You need to add the whole query, and especially the `SELECT` list, if you want a valid answer.

Comment: @ypercube What are you on about ? I already find the bug, please see my answer below, thank you

Comment: The answer, as it is, and the question is not helpful for others (in my opinion) because of the reasons of my comment above. Without the full query, or a better explanation of what the query is supposed to do, or some sample data and wanted output, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: A condition like you have `OR b.columnA IS NULL` on a join is very weird. Unless you do need something weird (like all the rows from table A when a NULL exists in table B, and those rows repeated in the result) it is unlikely to be useful. That's why I asked for the full query. to see what you want in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not working Statement

```
TableA Inner Join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA OR TableB.ColumnA = NULL
```

Working Statement

```
TableA Inner Join TableB on TableA.ColumnA = TableB.ColumnA OR TableB.ColumnA IS NULL
```

`TableB.ColumnA = NULL` was not working as expected !!!

Comment: Because `NULL` is not a value. TableB.ColumnA cannot `= NULL`

Comment: @MarkSinkinson Yup, that is right

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other operators may make this easier to understand, but perhaps slower to execute:

```
select
    *
from (

    select
        <whatever>
    from TableA

    INTERSECT

    select
        <whatever>
    from TableB     ) as TableC

UNION ALL

select
    <whatever>
from TableB
where <column> IS NULL
```